# SQLite and MySQL, will the conflict?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I just joined a project where they have been using SQLite. I am more comfortable using MySQL with PHPMyAdmin. If I install phpMyAdmin and work with that will it do any damage?

It is a php project. They have alot of code (sloppy code thats so hard to figure out) for accessing a SQLite db. I dont want to effect that but I want to add some new tables to a new db using mysql and phpmyadmin which i am yet to set up because I'm afraid it will break the code written for the SQLite db 
.

Comment: Why would you install a MySQL related tool to work with an SQLite database?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Where are you installing PHPMyadmin? What damage are you foreseeing? SQLLite is a simple database. If you are not ready to learn something as simple as SQLLite, you should consider switching to something else from programming.

Comment: so lets say i don't want to update anything thats already there I just want to add a new table and make a crud for it. rather than learn sqlite which i have no idea how it works, could i install phpmyadmin and mysql and make a new table in that and the work with it. Or, would adding phpMyAdmin and mysql ruin all the code thats written for sqlite even though i didnt get rid of anything realting to sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking merely about installing PHPMyAdmin to manage a SQLite database? That won't work, since both use completely different API's to be accessible through PHP.

Or do you wish to swap the SQLite database with MySQL and then use PHPMyAdmin to manage the database? That'll work, as long as the project supports both SQLite and MySQL.

Comment: How can i find out if the project supports both?

Comment: so lets say i don't want to update anything thats already there I just want to add a new table and make a crud for it. rather than learn sqlite which i have no idea how it works, could i install phpmyadmin and mysql and make a new table in that and the work with it. Or, would adding phpMyAdmin and mysql ruin all the code thats written for sqlite even though i didnt get rid of anything realting to sqlite.

Comment: You can install MySQL and PHPMyAdmin, but if the project you're working on uses SQLite, your actions will have zero impact. If you create a table, the app won't see it. If you delete a table, the app won't budge. If you uninstall MySQL... the app will still run. MySQL is simply totally unrelated to SQLite, apart from the 'SQL' part. They are different systems.

Comment: but if i make a new page that establishes a mysql connection properly (slecting the db in MySQL and the table i want to work with)  and then add some values PROPERLY... will that work?

Comment: Yes, but if anywhere in the code a call to, say, [sqlite_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php) is made, the site will fail, because that data isn't written to or read from your MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a PHP project? Probably not - `mysql_`-prefixed methods only work with MySQL as far as I know, and SQLite and MySQL don't listen on the same port by default, do they?

Comment: it is a php project. They have alot of code (sloppy code thats so hard to figure out) for accessing a SQLLite db. I dont want to effect that but I want to add some new tables to a new db using mysql and phpmyadmin which i am yet to set up because I'm afraid it will break the code written for the SQLLite db

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with what is deployed.  If the project is using Sqlite, then use that.  Databases are not all equal.  If you use something different, your code might not even run on the production databases.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you don't want affect, create a branch on github then from work this branch ..

you can also dump all table of this sqlite database to a sql file, then import this file to your phpAdmin, will create the table, since this both manager uses sql language ... just remove some ligne of code that are not compatible with mysql on sql file that you dump data from sqlite dabtase .....

here is the code for dump a sqlite database ....
first select the database on terminal on your project director

```
sqlite3
./open DATABASENAME

.output YOURSQLFILENAME.sql

.dump 

.quit
```

at this stage you already have your database in a sql file

then use php admin to import this file
if it show some error, just try to remove somecode that aren't compatible with mysql on sqlfile.